# Html content update doesn't take place when fading out

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a div that works as a curtain positioned over certain flash charts when these charts are changing their source datafile changed and if they find a problem they'll return an error (the problem is mainly when source datafile doesn't exist). The curtain div shows a 'loading' tag with an animated gif and is faded out when all charts are updated.

I've managed to control all this and have implemented also an error message to be shown when error occurs by changing html content using jQuery `html()` function. This is working ok and the error message is shown during certain time I've set up and after that I change its content.

The problem is when I try to reload new data I know exists and the curtain is positioned again over the charts. Its content is still the error message instead of the 'loading' tag and the gif. This only happens the first time datafile is change. At the second it works properly. I have changed `html()` function by the `append()` one adding also a calling to `empty()` without no luck, still have same issue.

I include some code:

```
if(error){
    $('#curtain').empty().append('<div class="errorDiv"><img src="error.png"/><span class="errorTag">Data not available</span></div>');
$('#curtain').fadeOut(1000,function(){
    $('#curtain').empty().append('<div id="loadingTagDiv"><img src="loader.gif"/><span id="loadingTag">Loading...</span></div>');   
});
}
```

Anyone knows what's happening?

----EDIT-------------------------
I'll sum up what I want:

1. Show (fading in) a curtain div over charts while they're loading new data with a 'loading...' tag.
2. If an error occurs, modifiy curtain div's content to show an error message. If not, just go to point #4, without need to modify content, as it'll be the default.
3. Wait certain ammount of time to make the user see the error.
4. Hide the div using fading out.
5. Modify div's content to be the default 'loading...' tag to make it ready to be shown when a new datafile the user wants to be loaded.

So far I've achieved to managed up to the forth point and the five is almost done. The problem is the content is not updated properly after an error loading new datafile is followed by a success datafile update.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't do the loader within the callback of the `fadeOut`.

So more like

```
$('#curtain').empty().append('<div id="loadingTagDiv"><img src="loader.gif"/><span id="loadingTag">Loading...</span></div>');
$('#curtain').fadeOut(1000);
```

the callback is fired after the `fadeOut` finished

Comment: But what I want is the div content to be updated after it is shown with the error message and then revert it to the 'default' state, which is with the 'loading' tag.